# Strict aliasing rule: static_cast vs reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, casting, undefined-behavior

Consider source type S and destination type D, which are **unrelated** types but have the same layout (for example S is a struct that simply wraps D, or vice versa, or S and D happen to have same data members in the same order, etc). Each of S and D can be either of primitive type or class type.

(A)

```
S* s;
D* d = reinterpret_cast<D*>(s);
//use d
```

(B)

```
S* s;
D* d = static_cast<D*>(static_cast<void*>(s));
//use d
```

I'm aware that we already have **undefined behaviour** when doing these casts, as per *strict aliasing rule* - although in practice it would most likely work.

Rules for strict aliasing is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). **Unrelated** means same layout but violate strict aliasing.

My question is:

Is (A) and (B) *exactly equivalent*? when

**(1).** S and D are unrelated, as stated above.

**(2).** S and D are related such that the casts do not violate strict aliasing rule, hence not UB.

Comment: (A) is not undefined behaviour if S actually starts with a D (and is standard-layout)   but you describe this as "unrelated" in your opening paragraph

Comment: Well if the classes you try to cast between have all members in same order and of same type it should work with reinterpret without problems

Comment: @MarošBeťko It is a strict aliasing violation in that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++14 (expr.reinterpret.cast/7), if `s` is correctly aligned for `D`, then the definition of `reinterpret_cast<D *>(s)` is `static_cast<D *>(static_cast<void *>(s))`.  So your two cases are exactly equivalent.

If there is an alignment violation then the result of the cast is unspecified,
 meaning it's effectively undefined behaviour if the result is dereferenced.

Note: The subsequent `// use d` may be undefined behaviour for various reasons; but if so, then it's either undefined in both cases, or the same well-defined behaviour in both.  You mention "strict aliasing" in the title, however strict aliasing concerns only apply to `*d` , not to the cast itself.

In C++11 it was required that `S` and `D` both be standard-layout types, otherwise the result is unspecified.

In C++03, it was only defined that, if `s` is correctly aligned for `D`, then `s == (S *)(D *)s`. It was not specifically required that `(D *)s` be usable in any other way than casting back to `S *`. Your two cases may have differed in C++03. This was obviously an unsatisfactory specification.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do earlier C++ versions say anything on this? Also, I think (until this answer, and at least before C++14) that the meaning `reinterpret_cast` is implementation-defined?

Comment: @PoweredByRice no, it is well-defined if alignment is correct

Answer (score 0):

> (1). S and D are unrelated, as stated above.

UB, simply because compiler is free to do whatever it wants to within allowed limits (for arch-specific optimization purposes, for example). And this might tiger something unexpected, though that would most likely depend on the structs S and D.

> (2). S and D are related such that the casts do not violate strict aliasing rule, hence not UB.

Still UB. Imagine that S and D are related. By casting from one to another actual pointed-to address may change. In reinterpret cast case there is actual code executed and pointed-to address also stays untouched. In other words you'll end up with invalid pointer, hence UB.

Comment: for (2), how can casting from one pointer to another change the address? that can only happen when you're casting from a derived class to a base class that is not *the first base class*, and that already violates strict aliasing.